# action bar not showing activity name

Tags: android, xml

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.allange">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want to see the activity name in the action bar . See the image of my action bar ...

[image]

Please help me

Comment: is that screenshot of design preview or real device?

Comment: It is the real device

Comment: post your java code also

Comment: Did you use ToolBar widget in your Activity?

Comment: Thanks Masum for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the following code was missing in my onCreate() method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Now, it's working 100%.